# Easy way to slide down an SVG element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

Is there an equivalent to jQuery's slideDown method for SVG elements?  Right now the elements just show up rather suddenly.  I would like to soften that a little by sliding down.

Edit:
I'm basing my code on the dynamic stacked bar graph here: http://benjchristensen.com/2011/12/16/dynamic-stacked-bar-chart-using-d3-js/

Instead of one graph with many bars, I have many graphs with one bar.  I want to make it so that when the graphs appear, it will slowly slide down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe that SVG is easily supported by jQuery.  Keith Wood has a [SVG specific jQuery library](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html#anim) that allows you to do some animation though.

A different option would be to use a graphics library that works with SVG.  The first that comes to mind is [D3.js](http://d3js.org/), which provides some very easy to use methods for manipulating SVG elements.  Additionally, the selector style is similar to what you may be used to for jQuery.

If you're using D3, I'd check out the [transition](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions) methods.  There's quite a bit you can do and D3 is incredibly powerful.  An example would be:

```
var rect = d3.select('#rectangle');
// this selects a rectangle.  Let's say that it starts at 
// the origin, or even off screen in your case   

rect.transition()
    .duration(250)
    .attr('x', 10)
    .attr('y', 20); 
    // this changes the x and y attributes
    // of the rectangle to 10 and 20 respectively
    // using a transition over a 250ms duration.
```

For the particular example that you gave, I would just change the `y` attribute so that it starts off screen (say `y = -1 * height`) and then transition it down to `y = height` or `y = 200` or something like that.

Comment: I'm actually using D3 but wasn't sure how to add animation to the elements.  Let me edit my original post.

Comment: If the code is appending something, I guess I should do the transition after the append? Or is it before?

Comment: @PLui Good question.  It really depends on how you have your code / data setup.  If you're appending SVG elements to the DOM using some data source, then you should use the "bind, enter, update, exit" model that Mike Bostock defines in his article ["Thinking with Joins"](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/).  You first define the element to be selected and then define how it will appear when new data is added (here you would use a `enter().append().attr().transition().duration().attr()` model).  Then you specify general updating.  And then how you want it to exit via `exit()`...

Comment: thanks for the link.  I read through some of that.  Based on what I read, if the following is my code to add a group in SVG:  <br/><br/> `var barGroup = d3.select("#" + chartId).selectAll("g.barChart")
    .append("g")
     .attr("class", "bar")
     .attr("id", chartId)
     .attr("style", "opacity:1.0")`  <br/><br/>I should be able to add a transition with the following? `.transition().delay(1000).duration(3000).attr("style", "opacity:0.1")`<br/> ?

Comment: if I want to select a group and move everything inside that group, how do I do that?

Comment: You'll have to play around with your selectors.  You could have you svg elements all given a class and use that as your selector or I think you can also do context specific selection just like with jQuery - so you could use the SVG:G group as your context.  But I think you're starting to deviate from the original topic.  Might be time for a new question.

Comment: I'd suggest animating the transform attribute instead, that works on <g> elements too.